# Cfx wsdl2java generates - 'The nested type Item cannot hide an enclosing type'

Tags: wsdl, cxf, jax-ws, wsdl2java, java2wsdl

Im trying to generate a WS client using CXF, however the generated classes have errors, in particular I am getting the following error:

```
The nested type Item cannot hide an enclosing type
```

Are there anyone CXF settings to deal with such situations?

The wsdl that I am using is:

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://example.org/AppGateway">
        <xsd:element name="ErrorResult">

            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                        minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="key">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="isSuccess" />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="errorCode" />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="errorMessage" />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="method" />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="msg" />
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="value">
                                    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                                        <xsd:sequence>
                                            <xsd:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                                minOccurs="0">
                                                <xsd:complexType>
                                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                                        <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="key" />
                                                        <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="value" />
                                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                                </xsd:complexType>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<message name="TestApiRequest">
    <part name="username" type="xsd:anyType" />
    <part name="password" type="xsd:anyType" />
</message>

<message name="TestApiResponse">
    <part name="Result" type="xsd:anyType" />
</message>

<message name="GetApiErrorListRequest">
    <part name="username" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="password" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
<message name="GetApiErrorListResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="Result" element="tns:ErrorResult"></wsdl:part>
</message>


<message name="AddTraderRecordRequest">
    <part name="username" type="xsd:anyType" />
    <part name="password" type="xsd:anyType" />
    <part name="traderRecord" type="xsd:anyType" />
</message>
<message name="AddTraderRecordResponse">
    <part name="Result" type="xsd:anyType" />
</message>
<portType name="AppGatewayPortType">
    <operation name="TestApi">
        <input message="tns:TestApiRequest" />
        <output message="tns:TestApiResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetApiErrorList">
        <input message="tns:GetApiErrorListRequest" />
        <output message="tns:GetApiErrorListResponse" />
    </operation>
    <operation name="AddTraderRecord">
        <input message="tns:AddTraderRecordRequest" />
        <output message="tns:AddTraderRecordResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>

<!-- Service definition -->
<wsdl:binding name="AppGatewayBinding" type="tns:AppGatewayPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        required="true" />
    <wsdl:operation name="TestApi">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.org/AppGateway/TestApi" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" type="soap:tBody"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" type="soap:tBody" required="true" parts="Result "/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetApiErrorList">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.org/AppGateway/GetApiErrorList" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

    <wsdl:operation name="AddTraderRecord">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.org/AppGateway/AddTraderRecord" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="AppGatewayEndpointService">
    <wsdl:port name="AppGatewayService" binding="tns:AppGatewayBinding">
        <http:address
            location="https://myserviceprovider.com/v1.1/SoapServer.php?className=AppGateway" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: You tagged it CXF, but refer in multiple places to CFX. Which is it?

Comment: Thats what happens after hours of bashing head on keyboard. Fixed.

Comment: Don't mind me, CFX is just part of cold fusion terminology, which runs on Java, so could have been related to CF. Good luck finding your answer.